# How can I display the time with two decimals from url parsing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am Parsing the time from URL as `02:00:00:00000` and I have displayed it in the `UITableViewCell`. It is displaying as `02:00:00:0000000` but I want to display like this `02:00`.

How can I get this and display it in `UITableView`.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple

```
 NSString *str=@"02:00:00:0000000";
 str=[str substringToIndex:5];
```